# How can i capture the stopped event of my java application which is running at background

Tags: java

i have developed a java application which will invoke automatically when system turn on after loading the windows. system user have to enter the details about him and access to the computer.the application will disapper and run in background. Now when he turnoff the system, background application will stop, at the time of stopping i want to capture the event and update status as logout in my database. is there any function to capture the event.

```
    package userauth;
    import java.awt.Cursor;
    import java.awt.SystemColor;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.URISyntaxException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
    import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
    import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
    import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
    import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

    class Home
    {
    static JFrame frame,frame1;
    static String facname,stdid;
   Home() throws IOException,URISyntaxException
   {

    frame = new JFrame("Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);

    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    java.net.URL url = Home.class.getResource("/fac.png");

    ImageIcon facimage = new ImageIcon(url);
    JLabel faclab = new JLabel(facimage);

    faclab.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    faclab.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {   
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getClickCount() > 0) {
             facframe();
                             }

      }
   });



    java.net.URL url1 = Home.class.getResource("/user.png");
    ImageIcon stuimage = new ImageIcon(url1);
    JLabel stulab = new JLabel(stuimage);

    stulab.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    stulab.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {


        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
             if (e.getClickCount() > 0) {
                 studentframe();
                                 }

          }
       });


    JLabel facl=new JLabel("Faculty");
    facl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    JLabel stdl=new JLabel("Student");
    stdl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    faclab.setBounds(450,250, 200, 200);
    stulab.setBounds(800,250, 200, 200);
    facl.setBounds(450, 475, 200, 20);
    stdl.setBounds(800,475,200,20);
    contentPane.add(faclab);
    contentPane.add(stulab);
    contentPane.add(facl);
    contentPane.add(stdl);
   frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
   frame.setSize(1500, 1000);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

   }
  protected static void facframe()
  {
    frame1 = new JFrame("Faculty");
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setUndecorated(true);
    frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    JLabel facnamefieldl=new JLabel("Faculty Name");
    JLabel deptlabel=new JLabel("Department");
    deptlabel.setBounds(400, 380, 140, 25);
    contentPane.add(deptlabel);
    facnamefieldl.setBounds(400, 350, 140, 25);
    contentPane.add(facnamefieldl);
    JTextField facname = new JTextField("");

    facname.setBounds(560, 350,200, 25);
    String depts[]={"Select Dept","Automobile","Mechanical(Btech)","Civil(Btech)","IT","CSE","ECE","EEE","MBA","Training","Mechanical(Poly tech.)","Civil(Poly tech.)","EEE(Poly tech.)"};        
    JComboBox deptnames=new JComboBox(depts);    
    deptnames.setBounds(560,380,150,25);    
    JButton submit=new JButton("Submit");
    JButton back=new JButton("Back");
    submit.setLayout(null);
    back.setBounds(560,445 , 80, 25);
    submit.setBounds(560,415 , 80, 25);

    contentPane.add(deptnames);
    contentPane.add(back);
    contentPane.add(facname);
    contentPane.add(submit);


    frame1.setSize(1500, 1000);
    frame1.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(false);
    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {

        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {

          facins(facname.getText(),deptnames.getSelectedItem().toString());


      }
        });

    }
    protected static void facins(String fname,String dept)
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String hostname=ip.getHostName();
            String str=ip.toString();
            facname=fname;

            String ipaddress=str.substring(str.indexOf("/")+1);
            if (fname.equals("")||dept.equals("Select Dept")){
                frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "please fill all the fields");
                frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

            }
            else
            {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userauth","root","");

            PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("insert into faculty(facname,dept,ipaddress,hostname,date)values(?,?,?,?,NOW())");
            stmt.setString(1, fname);
            stmt.setString(2, dept);
            stmt.setString(3, ipaddress);
            stmt.setString(4,hostname);

            int i=stmt.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0)
            {
                frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sucessfully updated");
                frame1.setVisible(false);
                frame.setVisible(false);




            }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception my)
        {
            System.out.println(my);
        }

     }
    protected static void studentframe()
    {

    frame1 = new JFrame("Student");
    frame1.setUndecorated(true);
    frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    JTextField  stname=new JTextField("");
     stname.setBounds(560, 350,200, 25);
     JTextField  stuid = new JTextField("");
    stuid.setBounds(560,380,150,25);
    JLabel namel=new JLabel("Student Name");
    JLabel idl=new JLabel("Student ID");
    namel.setBounds(400, 350, 140, 25);
    idl.setBounds(400, 380, 140, 25);
    JButton submit=new JButton("Submit");
    JButton back=new JButton("Back");
    submit.setLayout(null);
    back.setBounds(560,445 , 80, 25);
    submit.setBounds(560,415 , 80, 25);
    contentPane.add(namel);
    contentPane.add(idl);

    contentPane.add(stname);
    contentPane.add(stuid);
    contentPane.add(submit);
    contentPane.add(back);

    frame1.setSize(1500,700 );
    frame1.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(false);
    DocumentFilter filter = new UppercaseDocumentFilter();
    AbstractDocument firstNameDoc = (AbstractDocument) stuid.getDocument();
    firstNameDoc.setDocumentFilter(filter);

    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        // display/center the jdialog when the button is pressed
        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });


    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    try
    {
        Home.studentins(stname.getText(),stuid.getText());

    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {

    }
    }


    });

    }

    protected static void studentins(String stuname,String id) throws IOException
    {
      InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getLocalHost();

     String hostname=ip.getHostName();
     String str=ip.toString();
     stdid=id;
        String ipaddress=str.substring(str.indexOf("/")+1);
    if(stuname.equals("")||id.equals(""))
    {
        frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "please fill all the fields");
        frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    }
    else
    {
        try{


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userauth","root","");
    PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("insert into students(stname,stid,hostname,ipaddress,date)values(?,?,?,?,NOW())");
    stmt.setString(1, stuname);
    stmt.setString(2, id);
    stmt.setString(3,hostname);
    stmt.setString(4,ipaddress);

    int i=stmt.executeUpdate();
    if(i>0)
    {
        frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sucessfully updated");
        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame.setVisible(false);    


        }
        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
          }
         }


       }



     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, URISyntaxException
   {
    new Home();
       Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userauth","root","");
                    if(!facname.equals(""))
                    {
                    PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("update faculty set status=? where facname=?");
                    stmt.setString(1, "loggedout");
                    stmt.setString(2,stdid);
                    }
                    else if(!stdid.equals(""))
                    {
                        PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("update students set status=? where stid=?");
                        stmt.setString(1, "loggedout");
                        stmt.setString(2,stdid);

                    }



                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




            }
        });


       }
    }


    class UppercaseDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

       @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
    fb.insertString(offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
      }

@Override
     public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
    fb.replace(offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
      }

      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register a `Thread` to be run when

> The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or
>   when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
>
> The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt,
>   such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or
>   system shutdown.

See there : [Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

An example from the link below :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { database.close(); }
});
```

And some FaQ about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html) .

Comment: i have tried it with many modifications, but it is not effecting my database at all , i am posting code also please have a look at that

Comment: Could you log something to see if the `run` method gets called ?

Comment: Can you please rectify this